# Registros sendo inseridos em duas tabelas entre as Entidades com (doctrine - Foreign Key)

Tags: php, doctrine-2, zend-framework-2

Tenho duas tabelas, uma **Estados** e outra **Clientes**.
Ao inserir os registros nas duas tabelas, está ocorrendo um erro, ao invés de inserir a referência do estado na chave estrangeira da tabela **Clientes**, está inserindo o novo registro de estado na tabela **Estados**, e na tabela de Clientes, este novo estado é inserido no lugar da chave estrangeira.

O que eu preciso é apenas inserir na tabela **Clientes** no campo "estado_fk" o ID que peguei do Estado sem alterar nada na tabela Estado.

**O Controller**

```
    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $estado = new \Clientes\Entity\Estados();

    $estado->setId('2');
    $estado->setEstado('Minas Gerais');

    $cliente = new \Clientes\Entity\Clientes();
    $cliente->setNome('MEU NOME É');

    $cliente->setEstadoFk($estado);

    $em->persist($estado);
    $em->persist($cliente);

    $em->flush();

    die;
```

**A entidade Clientes**

```
   namespace Clientes\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * Clientes
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="clientes", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="estado_fk",        columns={"estado_fk"})})
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
   class Clientes
  {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nome", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $nome;

/**
 * @var \Estados
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Estados")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="estado_fk", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $estadoFk;

function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getNome() {
    return $this->nome;
}

function getEstadoFk() {
    return $this->estadoFk;
}

function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

function setNome($nome) {
    $this->nome = $nome;
}

function setEstadoFk(\Clientes\Entity\Estados $estadoFk) {
    $this->estadoFk = $estadoFk;
}

}
```

**A entidade Estados**

```
  namespace Clientes\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

  /**
  * Estados
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="estados")
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
  class Estados
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="uf", type="string", length=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $uf;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="estado", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $estado;

function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getUf() {
    return $this->uf;
}

function getEstado() {
    return $this->estado;
}

function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

function setUf($uf) {
    $this->uf = $uf;
}

function setEstado($estado) {
    $this->estado = $estado;
}


}
```

Comment: Provavelmente seu banco está com atribuição das chaves, veja se não há alguma restrição ou regra mapeada dentro do banco.

Comment: Veja que a entidade de clientes está mapeando também o estado:`
/**
    * Clientes
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="clientes", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="estado_fk",        columns={"estado_fk"})})
    * @ORM\Entity
    */` . acredito que quando você insere os dois registros no banco, o doctrine mapeado verifica a chave estrangeira do estado e passa para o usuário que você está cadastrando no `$cliente->setEstadoFk($estado);` com registro do usuário.

Comment: Beleza. Ivan, como que verifico em relação as chaves? Eu criei minha tabela com o seguinte código.

Comment: create table clientes(id int primary key auto_increment,
      nome varchar(100),
      estado_fk int);

Comment: create table estados(id int primary key auto_increment,
      uf char(2),
      estado varchar(30)
      );

Comment: alter table clientes add foreign key (estado_fk) REFERENCES estados(id);

Comment: Mas qual é o problema que vc quer corrigir? Se você não quer inserir o estado, arranque a referência: esta referência: `alter table clientes add foreign key (estado_fk) REFERENCES estados(id);`

Comment: `alter table clientes drop constraint RegraDoEstado`

Comment: para verificar as constraints do seu banco: `SELECT DISTINCT(constraint_name) 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE constraint_schema = 'seubanco' 
ORDER BY constraint_name ASC`;

Comment: O id do estado que eu  "selecionei", quero salvar na tabela Clientes (estado_fk) sem alterar nada na tabela Estado. Só que ele não está "setando" o id que peguei, ele está me trazendo um novo id (como se fosse um auto increment)

Comment: ahhh, agora entendi o problema, é melhor você editar sua pergunta porque não ficou claro. Pois vc disse "inserido um novo registro na tabela Estado".

Comment: É que esse é o problema kkkk mas vou formular melhor o titulo

Comment: Só um detalhe, por que você está passando o nome do estado, se você só quer pegar a referência?

Comment: Na verdade Ivan, é que estou fazendo vários testes porque estou quebrando a cabeça com isso.

Comment: porque vc não passa só a id 2 pra dentro do setEstadoFk

Comment: É que ele só aceita sendo uma instância de Estados

Comment: Você está me dizendo que no setEstadoFk, ele precisa receber a entidade?

Comment: No seu controller, tem como colocar o caminho dos **namespaces** usados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode pegar a entidade do estado desta maneira:

```
//coloque o caminho completo... 'Base\Model\...'
$estadoEntity = $em->getRepository('\Clientes\Entity\Estado')->findOneBy(
                    array(
                      'id' => 2
                    )
                );
```

Ou se quiser pegar pelo nome (**Obs:** se for usar *like*, tem que fazer uma query em **DQL**):

```
$estadoEntity = $em->getRepository('\Clientes\Entity\Estado')->findOneBy(
                        array(
                          'nome' => 'Minas Gerais'
                        )
                    );
   $id_estado = $estadoEntity->getId();
```

Para capturar todas as entidades:

```
$estadoEntity = $em->getRepository('\Clientes\Entity\Estado')->findAll();
```

E  pode fazer algo só assim, creio que também funciona:

```
 $estadoEntity =  $em->getRepository('\Clientes\Entity\Estado')
                  ->getId(2);
```

Comment: Então cara, agora ele até aceitou só que ele está gerando um novo registro na tabela Estado. :/

Comment: As Entidades foram geradas com o doctrine via Git Bash. Será se a entidade está incorreta?

Comment: Consegui... após fazer as alterações que você informou eu removi o  $em->persist($estado);

Comment: Ah legal! Se minha resposta te ajudou, marca a setinha verde lá. Obrigado.

Comment: Cliquei na setinha pra cima! Vlw. Abc

Comment: @DaniloMiguel, você precisa validar a resposta dando um ok nela (fica abaixo das setas).